# How to translate numbers from words to integers

Tags: python, function, dictionary

So in my main code if I call for 'four' , 'five' , and 'six', it will return the values of 4, 5, 6 using the function.

Inside the function I put the dictionary mapping:

```
def english_to_number (word):
      english_number = { 'zero': 0 , 'one': 1 , 'two': 2 , 'three': 3 , 'four': 4 , 'five': 5 , 'six': 6 , 'seven': 7 , 'eight': 8 , 'nine': 9 , 'ten': 10 }
```

Comment: You are missing a return....

Comment: You've stated your assignment. What is your question? What happens when you get `eleven`?

Comment: [Question is not clear](https://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion)

Comment: Add `return english_number[word]` at the end of the function

Answer (score 0):

You need to `get` the value from your dictionary (ideally setting a fallback in case it is not a key) and `return` the fetched value:

```
def english_to_number(word):
    english_number = {'zero': 0 , 'one': 1 , 'two': 2 , 'three': 3 , 'four': 4 , 'five': 5 , 'six': 6 , 'seven': 7 , 'eight': 8 , 'nine': 9 , 'ten': 10 }
    return english_number.get(word.lower(), 'I do not know this word')
```

example

```
>>> english_to_number('One')
1

>>> english_to_number('hundred')
'I do not know this word'
```

Comment: In the main program  I need to call the function for example: ‘zero’, ‘one’, ‘ten’, and print an informative statements with your results (e.g., “ ‘zero’ is 0“). How would I do this?

Comment: `def main(word): print(f"'{word}' is {english_to_number(word)}")`